# I can't understand this sentence from Peter hesseler's book called "country driving"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> At the moment it was rain, but I could see clearly what lay ahead; that forecast had been frozen atop the oncoming traffic.

I do not understand what "that forecast had been frozen atop the oncoming traffic" means here. Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Some surrounding sentences might help.
It sounds as if the driver is encountering rain (at the moment), but the vehicles in the oncoming traffic have ice on them (the forecast was perhaps for freezing rain). Thus, the driver was heading toward the area of freezing rain that the oncoming traffic had just left. The writer is expressing this figuratively by saying "the forecast was frozen atop the oncoming traffic".

Comment: oh I think I got it. The author is leaving A and heading to B. There is ice on top of the oncoming trucks so the author realises there is freezing rain in B right now. So the "forecast" is "frozen" on top of the oncoming traffic.